# List and access "Incoming" folder in Google Drive

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I want to list and access user's `Incoming` items using Google Drive Android API but I cannot find any method to do that in the [Drive API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/). I only know how to get the root of user Drive which refers to `My Drive` from the screenshot:

```
// The setup code is from https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java
Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();
About a = drive.about().get().execute();
id = a.getRootFolderId();
File driverootfolder = drive.files().get(id).execute();
// From here, can use Drive API to traverse user's Drive directories structure
```

[image: Incoming folder in Google Drive]

Unfortunately, the `Incoming` folder is not anywhere within `My Drive` and there is no method to obtain its ID. Is there a way to access it? My gut feeling is that third party app are NOT allowed to do so.

Comment: You can access those files if you have the file Id.. If the user added it to their drive, or selected it with a file picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Incoming** is not a real folder but simply a list of the files that have been shared with you.

You can use the following code to list the content of this folder :

```
drive.files().list().setQ("sharedWithMe").execute()
```

Beware though, the ordering is not the same, so with big **Incoming** folders where you need to paginate on the results, it can be hard to obtain the same file order as shown in Drive.